# NSDictionary inside NSMutableArray (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I need the following as a result:

```
(

    "some_key" = {
        "another_key" = "another_value";
    };

);
```

In order to do so, I have this code, but it doesn't work:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"another_value", @"another_key", nil];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array setValue:dictionary forKey:@"some_key"];
```

Any Idea? Thanks!

Comment: When I `NSLog` the array, it returns `()`.

Comment: The example you provided mixes array and dictionary syntax. It's not clear if the result should be a dictionary or an array.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Actually, `setValue:forKey:` is perfectly valid as a KVC accessor for `NSArray`s. Since the array is empty, it does nothing, though.

Comment: @Monolo I'm referring to the log output above. Also, I consider it very bad style to use `setValue:forKey:` on a dictionary as a normal accessor.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array setValue:dictionary forKey:@"some_key"];
```

------------^^^^^

You are setting this into array.

Try this one:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"another_value", @"another_key", nil];
NSDictionary *outDict=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:dictionary,@"some_key", nil];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:outDict, nil];
```

In new literals:

```
NSDictionary *d=@{@"another_key":@"another_value"};
NSDictionary *c=@{@"some_key":d};
NSArray *array=@[c];
```

Or nested creation :

```
NSArray *array=@[@{@"some_key":@{@"another_key":@"another_value"}}];
```

Comment: I like the nested creation the best.

Answer (score 4):

An `NSMutableArray` can normally be built by just adding objects to the end. the method is `addObject:`

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"another_value", @"another_key", nil];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:dictionary];
```

On the other hand, if you want to address the dictionary by a key (@"some_key"), then you need the outer container to be a dictionary, too:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"another_value", @"another_key", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *outerDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[outerDict setObject:dictionary forKey:@"some_key"];
```

Answer (score 2):

From the docs

> setValue:forKey: - Sets the property of the receiver specified by a
>   given key to a given value.

That's `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol. You're using the wrong method to add an object to an array, `NSArray` is an ordered collection, not a dictionary. The easiest way to do what you need is:

```
NSDictionary* dic = @{@"some_key": @{@"another_key": @"another_value"}};
```

As you can see the output is a `NSDictionary` not a `NSArray`.

Answer (score 2):

Array's do not use `setValue:forKey:` (nor `setObject:forKey:`) and arrays are not associative like Dictionaries.

`setValue:forKey:` is KVC (Key Value Coding).

You want an Array of dictionaries of dictionaries (below in pseudo plist form)

```
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>someKey</key>
    <dict>
      <key>someOtherKey</key>
      <string>someValue</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
  <dict>
    <key>someKey</key>
    <dict>
      <key>someOtherKey</key>
      <string>someValue</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
  <dict>
    <key>someKey</key>
    <dict>
      <key>someOtherKey</key>
      <string>someValue</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
  <dict>
    <key>someKey</key>
    <dict>
      <key>someOtherKey</key>
      <string>someValue</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</array>
```

`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this kind of structure

```
NSDictionary *anotherKeyValueDictionary = 
 [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"another_value", 
                                              @"another_key", nil];
NSDictionary *someKeyValueDictionary = 
 [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"anotherKeyValueDictionary", 
                                              @"some_key", nil];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:someKeyValueDictionary];
```